# FlowLayoutPanel scrolling to picture box and focusing on it

Tags: vb.net, select, scroll, focus, flowlayoutpanel

I have a FlowLayoutPanel that I populate with Picture Boxes with this code:

```
    If Me.cbDisplayThumbnails.Checked then
    ' Displaying thumbnails of the images
    Me.picBox.Visible = False
    Me.thumbNailPanel.Controls.Clear
    Me.thumbNailPanel.Visible = True  
    For i As Integer = 0 to bmpList.Count-1
        Dim picViewer As New PictureBox
        picViewer.Image = bmpList(i)
        picViewer.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        picViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
        picViewer.Height = 300
        picViewer.Width = 300
        picViewer.Name = i.ToString
        AddHandler picViewer.Click, AddressOf thumbnail_Click
        Me.thumbNailPanel.Controls.Add(picViewer)
    Next
    Exit Sub 
End If
```

I then want to focus on one of the picture boxes based on its index in the panels control collection. Here is what I have tried:

```
            Me.thumbNailPanel.Enabled = True
            Me.thumbNailPanel.Controls(thePage).Focus
```

I also tried 
    Me.thumbNailPanel.Controls(thePage).Select 
and
    Me.thumbNailPanel.ScrollControlIntoView(Me.thumbNailPanel.Controls(thePage)

Neither work.

I have AutoScroll = True. There are 64 picture boxes in the panel. I want to have the panel scroll down to the selected picture box and focus on it.

Comment: A `PictureBox` can't receive focus so that part is out. Only controls that can receive user input can receive focus. A `Label` can't receive focus for the same reason.

Comment: As for ensuring that the `PictureBox` can be see, you would need to call `ScrollControlIntoView` on your `FlowLayoutPanel`. Hmmm... I see that you did call `ScrollControlIntoView`. Did you set `AutoScroll` to `True` on the `FlowLayoutPanel` or the form?

Comment: I did set autoscroll to true on the form

Comment: Then that was your mistake. If you expect the `FlowLayoutPanel` to scroll one of its child controls into view then you need to set `AutoScroll` to `True` on the `FlowLayoutPanel`. Setting it on the form only allows the form to scroll the `FlowLayoutPanel` into view.

Comment: I am sorry, what I meant was I set autoscroll ture for the FlowControlPanel in the VS IDE. I did not set the form's autoscroll to true.

Comment: I just did the following: created a new WinForms app project, added a `Button` to the form, added a `FlowLayoutPanel` and set `AutoScroll` to `True`, added 12 `PictureBox` controls, handled the `Click` event of the `Button` and added `FlowLayoutPanel1.ScrollControlIntoView(PictureBox12)`. When I clicked the `Button`, the last `PictureBox` was scrolled into view, exactly as expected. If it's not working for you then you have done something wrong. I suggest that you strip things back to the minimum and confirm that it works for you to, then build up to your final design and see where it breaks.

Comment: I just set the `Dock` of all my `PictureBox` controls to `Bottom` and tried again and it didn't work, so that's likely what's causing your issue. I was wondering why you did that from the start, because it doesn't seem to serve a purpose.  Remove the line that sets the `Dock` property and see if it works then.

Comment: In fact, I just scrolled manually to the bottom and clicked the `Button` and the panel scrolled back to the top. I'm not sure why that is the case but, as I said, I can't see a reason for setting `Dock` at all anyway.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Thank you very much. I believe I got that code snippet from another posting somewhere but I agree, I do not see why the picture box should be docked.